# Does AngularJS make Turbolinks pointless?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, turbolinks

From Turbolinks page:

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
>   Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS
>   between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body and the title in the head

If I want to build a rich client-side application with AngularJS, does that framework make pointless Turbolinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. They both work differently and and their main goal is different.

Turbolinks work on a Rails webapp that responds with HTML.

Angular JS or any other JS frameworks makes use of a JSON API backend.

There is not extra coding required to use turbolinks. Turbolinks is just a way of making pages to load faster by minimizing the content that is being transferred. Only replacing the HTML body tag

With JS framework, you have to build the entire front-end application. This is particularly useful as the same backend can be used to develop mobile apps

Comment: Yeah, but doesnt Angular also replace the body tag, making it the same as turbolinks to that effect?

Comment: In angular, html templating happens in the frontend. Angular has an inbuilt templating engine, but while using turbolinks the app server spits out HTML.

Comment: If the way you build your AngularJS app is with partials that you have to fetch from an URL, those are "spit out" as well by the server.